# C# / WPF - Getting object inside a child user control from parent window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Not terribly familiar with WPF and C# so if this is blatantly wrong, please correct me. Working in VSExpress2015 .NET Framework 4.5. I'm heavily simplifying my code below, so know that namespace/library references are there.

Say I have a window with a Button and ContentControl inside:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="Submit_Btn" Click="Submit_Btn_Click">
        <ContentControl Name="MainContentControl">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I also have several user control files in my project with XAML that looks something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.UserControl1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="TxtBox1">
    </Grid>
</Usercontrol>
```

I have code in the backend of my MainWindow to dynamically load the appropriate UserControl into the "MainContentControl" object. However, I want to reference the objects *inside* of the currently loaded UserControl from the MainWindow's Submit_Btn_Click function. For example, in MainWindow.cs, do something like this:

```
private void Submit_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MainContentControl is currently loaded with UserControl1)
        Do_Something_Function(MainContentControl.TxtBox1.Text);
}
```

The main problem here is I don't know how to call the TextBox1 element from within the parent MainWindow's scope. I'm also not sure how to validate the if condition (confirming the control is currently loaded). Does anyone know of a way to think about this differently or even directly reference the object (despite that probably not being a great idea)?

--

*I'm not using/familiar with MVVM at all (yet), and I'm not particularly concerned with optimal performance as this is a one off temporary project that will soon die and be re-worked. I've read ways how to access the data in a parent window from a child, but I didn't find scenarios that really matched up with this.*

*Once again, I'm still familiarizing myself with C#, WPF and general coding practices (it's been a couple years), so if using a ContentControl or UserControl here isn't optimal, (or mixing the two doesn't make sense) that information would be greatly appreciated; however, in this scenario, I'm more concerned with just getting this working until I can learn more proper techniques later.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely looks like the design should be improved, but just to get this working you can do the following:

```
    private void Submit_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var controlAsUserControl1 = MainContentControl.Content as UserControl1;
        if (controlAsUserControl1 != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(controlAsUserControl1.TxtBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works flawlessly with what I am trying to accomplish right now. Both pulling the value and validation it's loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LogicalTreeHelper` to search by name.

So for your example to access `TextBox1`

```
 var txtBox = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(MainContentControl, "TextBox1") as TextBox;
 Do_Something_Function(txtBox?.Text);
```

Comment: added null propegation to prevent exception.

Comment: I actually read about this route, but I wont be able to directly reference "txtBox?.Text" here though as ".Text" doesn't exist in the scope until the code runs. IntelliSense won't be able to see it and thus throw a compile error.

Comment: added a cast. then you can reference it

Comment: Ah. I can confirm this works; although, I'm not as keen on using here it as object elements are typed out as strings and won't be recognized by the IDE. Still good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to access the TextBox inside the UserControl, you can expose properties and methods on the UserControl itself to interact with what's inside. In your case, you could add a property that returns the current value of TextBox.Text. You can also add dependency properties to facilitate binding.

Comment: Still learning about binding. So, if I had public getters/setters to return object values like the "TxtBox.Text" string, what would be the proper method of invoking those functions from MainWindow? Would data binding expose those functions even without IntelliSense knowing what was loaded into the "MainContentControl" first? ...Or is accessing dynamically loaded content into a ContentControl just bad design altogether?

Comment: For public properties/methods, you would just access it via `UserControl1.Property` or `UserControl1.Method()`. Dependency Properties can be accessed just like any other property, but would support binding from wherever you use UserControl1. IntelliSense would know about any public properties/DPs/methods. The dynamically loaded content is the value of the property, not the property itself, so that in itself is not a bad design.